# List with responsive shifts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an un-ordered list that looks like this on a full size page:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5               <some content here>
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
```

But I want it to go to:

```
Item 1               Item 4                Item 7
Item 2               Item 5                Item 8
Item 3               Item 6                Item 9

<some content>
```

at 100% width of a phone.

I have the list and "other content" in divs doing what I need, but in regards to the list, should I use tables, or is there CSS that I can use with an un-ordered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
       ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 300px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        li {
            flex: 1;
            min-height: 100px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

adjust the height of ul and li to fit your design needs

Comment: Thank you, will work well! I now have some new CSS terms to look up.

Comment: you're welcome James..new but very useful .. Learn Flexbox at your earliest convenience..you will be shocked by its power..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:33
}
```